# Datatables plugin error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the [jQuery Datatables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/). Pagination was not working so I tried to initialise the datatable after appending my rows using ajax/jQuery in the hopes that once all the rows are added and datatables is then initialised, it would work. But I am getting an error:

```
 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined."
```

I just want pagination to work, so I am not even sure if this is the right approach for that when the rows are added via jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<table id="table" class="table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Route</td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tablebody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
function loadfromDB(event) {
var uid = $('#uid').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getplans.php",
            data: {uid:uid},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            $('input').removeClass('error').next('.errormessage').html('');
            if(!response.errors && response.result) {
                 $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
                   $("#tablebody").append('<tr><td>'+value[4]+'</td><td>'+value[2]+'</td><td>'+value[3]+'</td></tr>');

                  }); 
             $('#table').DataTable();
            } 

            else {
                $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
                    // add error classes
                    $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
                });
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Check your table structure, make sure table header is same to table cell.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I checked and realised I my <thead> had an extra column. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your table structure, make sure table header is same to table cell.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header 1</th>
            <th>header 2</th>
            <th>header 3</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>table cell 1</td>
            <td>table cell 2</td>
            <td>table cell 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can build your datatables using ajax as a data source (I wont write about it, it is well documented on the datatables siet, please view it there).
2. adding data AFTER the init. is simple. i show u an example:

var myTable = $('#myTableId').DataTable({ /*... set up options here */ });

a) make sure u return a valid JSON from the server, CORRESPONDING withe input your datatbles expect
b) modif. the ajax request to recive and parse JSON
c) in the SUCCESS callback of the response:

```
    // this 2 lines to recive and parse JSON
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",

    success: function(json) {

     // first, empty the table:
     myTable.clear();

     // add the data and redraw the table:
     myTable.rows.add(json).draw();


    }
```

Comment: Thanks @iModi. I will definitely consider rewriting my code as your approach seems a lot cleaner. I appreciate it. My issue has however been solved thanks to Code Demon. A small oversight on my part.

Comment: i would strongly NOT recommend messing with the table dom after rendering outside the datatables env. it will give you hours of bugtracking and headache (i went through it). refresh the data object if changed and redraw the table. dont mess with the already rendered DT object.

Comment: Great, I shall rewrite my code now and save myself the headache than go for the quick-fix. Thanks for your input sir!